# error in implimantation of intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I have written the following code in java file in eclipse to make launch of snapchat application on my android device through my application. But when i am running it in my android device it shows "no apps can perform this action".

```
if(view.getId()==R.id.LaunchSnapchat){
    intent= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("snapchat://details?id=com.snapchat.android&hl=en&rdid=com.snapchat.android"));
    chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent,"Launch Snapchat");
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

what is the solution??

Comment: If you want directly launch snapchat, set package to your intent.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open Snapchat"));
```

Also work this it is because mabe you did not have snapchat installed (emulator)

```
if(view.getId()==R.id.LaunchSnapchat){
    intent= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("snapchat://details?id=com.snapchat.android&hl=en&rdid=com.snapchat.android"));
    chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent,"Launch Snapchat");
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, as taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574735/6151924)

> If you don't know the main activity, then the package name can be used to launch the application.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.snapchat.android");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```